# To store last timestamp of a file in java

Tags: java

I have written a piece of code to compare time stamp to check for file modification

Here is the code

```
private long timeStamp;
private File file;

private boolean isFileUpdated(File file)
{
  this.file = file;
  this.timeStamp = file.lastModified();
  if (this.timeStamp != timeStamp)
  {
   this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
   // Yes, file is updated
   return true;
  }
  // No, file is not updated
  return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Test test=new Test();
  File testFile=new File("D:/Test/Test.txt");
  boolean result=test.isFileUpdated(testFile);
  System.out.println("the result is  " + result);
}
```

The problem with this code is it doesn't maintain any history of timestamp. So do I need to place the timestamp in a txt file so that it reads from the txt file and compares it will current lastmodifieddate and if there is change that means a file has been modified?

Comment: This will cause creation and maintenance of new file anyways this can be reduced.Note I cant use DB and i am using java 1.6

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: the question how to maintain the lastmodifieddate so the it can compared with current one

Comment: Isn't that what you are doing already?

Comment: Yes but if i will run this code again the timestamp will again goes back to zero and there wont be any history.What i am trying to say is it wont be having last modified date

Comment: Some kind of listener which can let me know if the file has been modified without adding any new library ???
Thats what i am trying to do

Answer (score 1):

This will write your history for you:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(FileWriter(new File("log.log"), true));
//true for append mode
writer.println(file.lastModified());
writer.close();
```

You can read it in with a Scanner like this

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("log.log"));
String line = null;
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    line = s.nextLine();
}
s.close();
//line is the last line read
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid to create a file